# How to remove '.do' prefix from url in Struts1?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, struts-1

I have written a web-application in Struts 1 framework. Everything works fine but on form submission when user is forwarded to next page URL which is shown is `actionname.do`. I don't want this Struts 1 default suffix on URL. Instead of it I would like to see page's name in URL. How to do it?

Note : I have tried editing servlet mapping in `web.xml`. Have replaced `/*.do` . But In that case even my index page doesn't open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open `/WEB-INF/web.xml`
2. You will have to find the `servlet-name` of the `org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet` and the `servlet-mapping` that corresponds to the `servlet-name`.

For example:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Finally, simply change the `url-pattern` to what you desire and redeploy the application.

Comment: I have tried it , I have edited question accordingly :)

Comment: Can you try `<url-mapping>/<url-mapping>`?

Comment: This removed .do from url but I want to display that page name, On which user is forwarded.In this case it show actioname in url

Answer (score 4):

In your web.xml, replace url pattern `*.do` with `/`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: This removed .do from url but I want to display that page name, On which user is forwarded.In this case it show actioname in url

Answer (score 2):

Modify  in `web.xml` and change `*.do`

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I have tried it , I have edited question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use this mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/c/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then use [Tuckey URL rewriter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) rule to change this to `/*`

```
<rule>
  <from>^/(\w+)*/$</from>
  <to>/c/$1</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: It seems that it will work for me, but I have a question that this will be configured in a filter, right? So url will be changed to home.jsp(I am considering that next page is login.jsp which should be open) as soon as if control goes to action class.What if an error has occurred and next page which will be open will be showerror.jsp? As It will show home.jsp

Comment: It's unclear what you asking, could you post `struts-config.xml`?